# Destructuring array of objects in typescript (Ionic)

Tags: arrays, typescript, object, ionic-framework

I am trying to get an array of objects from an API and print their details with ngFor loop. However I have run into problem of accessing the specific attributes. My backend structure looks like this:

```
export interface Root {
  response: Response[]
}

export interface Response {
  id: string
  title: string
  text: string
  type: string
  images: any[]
  location: Location
  isDinner: boolean
  isDelivery: boolean
  storeInfo: StoreInfo
  categoryId: string
}

export interface Location {
  type: string
  coordinates: number[]
}

export interface StoreInfo {
  id: string
  geoLocation: GeoLocation
  userPoint: number
  workingHours: any[]
  status: string
  rate: number
  minOrderPrice: number
}

export interface GeoLocation {
  latitude: number
  longitude: number
}
```

From here I am not able to get `id`, `title`, `text` etc. because I could not destructure them from "response"

My service file looks like this:

```
export interface ApiResult {
  response: [];
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class RestaurantsService {
  input = {
    skip: 0,
    limit: 5,
    latitude: 38.418523,
    longitude: 27.127399,
  };

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getCloseRestaurants(): Observable<ApiResult> {
    const header = new HttpHeaders({
      accept: 'application/json',
      apiKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
      contentType: 'application/json',
    });
    //let body
    return this.http.post<ApiResult>(
      `https://smarty.kerzz.com:4004/api/mock/getFeed`,
      this.input,
      {
        headers: header,
      }
    );
  }
}
```

And my page file:

```
export class RestaurantsPage implements OnInit {
  restaurants = [];

  constructor(
    private restaurantsService: RestaurantsService,
    private loadingCtrl: LoadingController
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadRestaurants();
  }

  async loadRestaurants() {
    const loading = await this.loadingCtrl.create({
      message: 'Loading..',
      spinner: 'bubbles',
    });
    await loading.present();

    this.restaurantsService.getCloseRestaurants().subscribe((res) => {
      loading.dismiss();
      this.restaurants = [...res.response, ...this.restaurants];
      console.log(res.response);
    });
  }
}
```

The log at the end returns this: [Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTuZ7.png)
However I can only use res.response nothing else. For example it does not let me do res.response[0]. It says 0th element is empty.

When I iterate through `*ngFor="let item of restaurants"` and destructure with {{item}} it returns me this:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJNGK.png)

Comment: Terminology: deconstruction is the opposite of construction. It's not even a concept in JS but other languages might have code that runs when an instance is being destroyed. Thus the opposite of construction which is when an instance is being created. It's not at all related to *destructuring assignment* in JS. The term comes from "de-structuring", when you have a structure and pull it apart into its composites.

Comment: Well, if you just output your `{{item}}`  it will implicitly call `item.toString()` which results in the output you see, because that's what `object.toString()` returns if not overridden.

Comment: You are doing it wrong. you should NOT be destructuring a response. Just use res. response